# How to upgrade from ionic framework v1.2.4 to ionic framework v2.0.0-beta using npm

Tags: angular, npm, ionic2

I am trying to upgrade my ionic framework from version 1.2.4 to the latest ionic framework version 2.0.0 -beta version via node package manager (npm). I found an example from the [documentation website](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/installation/) `npm install -g ionic@beta` but I keep getting this error

> 14 error node v0.12.7
>   15 error npm  v2.11.3
>   16 error code EISDIR
>   17 error errno -4068
>   18 error EISDIR, read
>   19 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
>   19 error     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>   20 verbose exit [ -4068, true ]

Answer (score 1):

Well, well, well.

Remember ionic1 project can't be shifted to ionic2 because the projects structure is completely changed in ionic2.

Ionic 2 use `TypeScript`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I found out that to upgrade an npm package I have to:

> run npm as an administrator first

Before I can run the code, I must execute:

```
npm install -g ionic@beta
```

After that it works fine.